# Let $f(x,y,z)$ = $\mathbf c$ $\cdot$ $\mathbf x$ = $ax + by + cz$, where $\mathbf c$ = $(a,b,c)$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y,z)$ = $\mathbf c$ $\cdot$ $\mathbf x$ = $ax + by + cz$, where $\mathbf c$ = $(a,b,c)$ $\in$  $\mathbb R^3$. Then

$\nabla$$f(x,y,z)$ = $(a,b,c)$ = $\mathbf c$

In the context of gradients, what is does this mean? I only just started learning about gradients, but I do not understand what this scenario is. I've only seen gradients with a function, rather than the dot product of two vectors. If someone could please explain this concept and what it means, I would appreciate it. Also, please explain its significance.

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes, apologies.

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is a scalar.  You will see later on in your course how certain equations of planes and hyper surfaces can be constructed with dot products.  Saying that the gradient is a constant is analgous to a linear equation in the single variable case.  The gradient is the multivariable equivilent to the derivative.  It means that the directional derivative is not dependent on the point only the direction it is pointing in.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows But what is its relation to the dot product, as that presented in the OP? What is this saying and why are we using dot products instead of a function? I honestly can't tell if you're answering these questions specifically, since I don't understand them in the first place (hence asking the question). If you're answering the OP, you'll need to specify that more clearly.

Comment: @ThePointer Your questions is exceptionally vague.  The dot product maps V to R.  It lets you turn two vectors into a real number.  For example the equation of a plane is the dot product of a normal vector and a position vector.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows I know what the dot product is. My question relates to its use in relation to gradients, as in the above example. I have never dealt with dot product in a situation with gradients - I have only dealt with functions. I am looking for clarification on what the gradient is referring to, in this context, where we have the dot product of two vectors, instead of a function.

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is a function.  It is just a different way of writing it.  The dot product function pretty much the same way as multiplication.  It follows most of the same rules.  It follow a very similar power rule to the one you learned in single variable calculus.